# I want to know how to use ActionScript3.0 to use GraphQL

Tags: actionscript-3, graphql

We are currently using 'GraphQL' with backend made of node.js(use 'apollo-server-express') and frontend made of react(use 'apollo-client', 'react-apollo-hooks').

I want to use 'GraphQL' in 'adobe AIR', but I can't find a way to implement it.

It would be appreciated if you could tell me how to send Query and Mutation from AIR to backend.

Add question: How do I write 'URLRequest data' in 'AIR' to send 'Query' like this?

```
export const GROUP_INFOS = gql`
query {
 groupInfos {
  idx
  name
 }
}`;
```

Comment: All you need to do is send a HTTP request to your backend server. Assuming ActionScript allows HTTP requests your good to go!

Comment: URLRequestMethod.POST, jsoned query/mutation and variables, search for curl examples for details

Comment: DanStarns, xadm Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, we haven't solved the problem yet.

Comment: You need a better example of a query.  No programming language can make a HTTP query using `export const ... etc`. Check the **GraphQL** manual for HTTP endpoints where request should be send, and also how to structure the request